# Dynamically call functions in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to test a Python library called [Tulip](https://github.com/cirla/tulipy) dynamically. To do it I need to call the proper `ti.<indicator_name>` and pass the arguments to call the method.

The problem is, each method has fixed number of parameters and I don't know how to pass it properly.

Let's say I want to test `ti.sma` method that requires two arguments **real** and **period**

```py
def sma(real, period):
    """
    Simple Moving Average
    """

    return lib.sma([real], [period])
```

So, I would need to call it as:

```py
sma_test = ti.sma(real=[25,20,22,30,22,28,25,30,21,23,24,22], period=5)
```

So my question is, how do I call the method above dynamically using  the json below as payload?

```json
{
    "short_name": "sma",
    "data": [74.333511, 73.61084, 74.197395, 73.848442, 75.036385, 76.630219, 76.803459, 77.385063],
    "period": 5
}
```

I have made this validator where I could get the function object but how about the parameters?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tulipy as ti
import datetime
import uuid
import inspect

def validate_indicator(payload):
    data = np.array(payload.get('data'))
    try:
        indicator = getattr(ti, payload.get('short_name'))
        validation_test = indicator(data)
```

If I run the code above I get the Exception `TypeError` obviously because I didn't pass the required argument `period` in `output = indicator(data)`. I believe the way to get there is to make a new function with optional `*args`

```py
validate_indicator(
{
    "short_name": "sma",
    "data": [74.333511, 73.61084, 74.197395, 73.848442, 75.036385, 76.630219, 76.803459, 77.385063],
    "period": 5
}
)

Result:
"sma() missing 1 required positional argument: 'period'"
```

Another example, if I want to test `ti.bbands` that requires **real**, **period** and **stddev** as arguments.

```py
def bbands(real, period, stddev):
    """
    Bollinger Bands
    """

    return lib.bbands([real], [period, stddev])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can use `**kwargs`:

File `test.py`

```py
import test2

data = {
    "short_name": "sma",
    "data": [74.333511, 73.61084, 74.197395, 73.848442, 75.036385, 76.630219, 76.803459, 77.385063],
    "period": 5
}

f = getattr(test2, data.pop('short_name'))
f(**data)
```

File `test2.py`:

```py
def sma(data, period):
    print(data)
    print(period)
```

```
> python3 test.py
[74.333511, 73.61084, 74.197395, 73.848442, 75.036385, 76.630219, 76.803459, 77.385063]
5
```

Note:
If you want to use `*args`, you could call the function as:

```
f(*[value for value in data.values()])
```

### Edit

This would be a function that accepts the data dict as a parameter and calls the corresponding function for you:

```py
def validate_function(data):
    f = getattr(ti, data.pop('short_name'))
    f(**data)
```

Comment: if I want to call `bbands` now?

Comment: if you want to call bbands, you need another data dict that contains `bbands` value for the `short_name` key, and an entry for each of its arguments